# Как правильно организовать извлечение дочерних комментариев в древовидной структуре?

Tags: mysql, алгоритм

Я делаю комментарии, они должны быть древовидны и у них есть всего одна степень вложенности (прим. комменты на ютубе).

Структура таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE `_fx_comments` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`sender` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`recipient` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`target` varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
`eid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`text` text, 
`rateTrue` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`rateFalse` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`resource` text, 
`approve` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
`isDel` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
KEY `pid` (`pid`), 
KEY `sender` (`sender`), 
KEY `recipient` (`recipient`), 
KEY `target` (`target`), 
KEY `eid` (`eid`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`eid` - id элемента которому принадлежат комментарии, `pid` - id коммента-родителя

Основная задача которую мне нужно решить - это извлечь допустим последние 10 комментов у которых `pid IS NOT NULL`, 
и както смотреть если у текущего коммента есть дочерние - то извлечь их (два дочерних - последние добавленные).

Но теперь как-то надо извлечь последние два дочерних..... Есть мысль использовать NESTED SET, но не знаю как применить его на моем примере.

**UPDATE**:

На данный момент есть такой ужасный вариант решения задачи:

```
SELECT fx_cmt.id,fx_cmt.pid,fx_cmt.eid,fx_cmt.sender,fx_cmt.recipient,fx_cmt.date,fx_cmt.text,fx_cmt.rateTrue,fx_cmt.rateFalse,fx_cmt.resource,
        fx_u.fx_login AS senderLogin, fx_u2.fx_login AS recipientLogin,
        (SELECT COUNT(fx_cmt_count.id)  FROM _fx_comments fx_cmt_count WHERE fx_cmt_count.pid = fx_cmt.id) AS countChilds,

         fx_cmt_l.id AS lcId, fx_cmt_l.pid AS lcPid, fx_cmt_l.eid AS lcEid, fx_cmt_l.sender AS lcSender, fx_cmt_l.recipient AS lcRecipient, fx_cmt_l.date AS lcDate,
             fx_cmt_l.text AS lcText, fx_cmt_l.rateTrue AS lcRateTrue, fx_cmt_l.rateFalse AS lcRateFalse, fx_cmt_l.resource AS lcResource,

         fx_cmt_pl.id AS plcId, fx_cmt_pl.pid AS plcPid, fx_cmt_pl.eid AS plcEid, fx_cmt_pl.sender AS plcSender, fx_cmt_pl.recipient AS plcRecipient, fx_cmt_pl.date AS plcDate,
             fx_cmt_pl.text AS plcText, fx_cmt_pl.rateTrue AS plcRateTrue, fx_cmt_pl.rateFalse AS plcRateFalse, fx_cmt_pl.resource AS plcResource,

         fx_u_l.fx_login AS lcSenderLogin, fx_u2_l.fx_login AS lcRecipientLogin,
         fx_u_pl.fx_login AS plcSenderLogin, fx_u2_pl.fx_login AS plcRecipientLogin

FROM _fx_comments AS fx_cmt 

INNER JOIN _fx_users fx_u ON fx_u.id = fx_cmt.sender
LEFT JOIN _fx_users fx_u2 ON fx_u2.id = fx_cmt.recipient

LEFT JOIN _fx_comments fx_cmt_l ON fx_cmt_l.id = (SELECT id FROM _fx_comments AS c WHERE c.pid = fx_cmt.id  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1)
LEFT JOIN _fx_comments fx_cmt_pl ON fx_cmt_pl.id = (SELECT id FROM _fx_comments AS c WHERE c.pid = fx_cmt.id  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1,1)

LEFT JOIN _fx_users fx_u_l ON fx_u_l.id = fx_cmt_l.sender
LEFT JOIN _fx_users fx_u2_l ON fx_u2_l.id = fx_cmt_l.recipient
LEFT JOIN _fx_users fx_u_pl ON fx_u_pl.id = fx_cmt_pl.sender
LEFT JOIN _fx_users fx_u2_pl ON fx_u2_pl.id = fx_cmt_pl.recipient

WHERE fx_cmt.eid = 1
```

Но этот вариант хоть и работает, но он ужасен, поэтому нужно более корректное решение....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно изобразить что то в таком роде:

```
select *
  from (
        select if(N=1,    id,
               if(N=2,  l_id,
                       ll_id)) id,
               id as P_ID,
               N
          from (select id,
                       (select id from _fx_comments L
                         where L.pid=C.id
                         order by date desc limit 0,1) as l_id,
                       (select id from _fx_comments L
                         where L.pid=C.id
                         order by date desc limit 1,1) as ll_id
                  from _fx_comments C
                 where pid is null
                 order by date desc
                 limit 10) A,
                (select 1 as N union select 2 union select 3) B
    ) A
 inner join _fx_comments fx_cmt on fx_cmt.id=A.id
  left join _fx_users fx_u ON fx_u.id = fx_cmt.sender
  left join _fx_users fx_u2 ON fx_u2.id = fx_cmt.recipient
 order by P_ID, N
```

Задача основного подзапроса получить ID последних 10 каментов и рядом с ними ID последнего и предпоследнего дочернего камента. После чего это перемножается на запрос выдающий номера 1, 2, 3. Далее IF разворачивает все полученные ID по вертикали, в одну колонку. К этому можно уже клеить основную информацию из каментов и других таблиц. Для удобства сортировки итоговой выдачи из опорного подзапроса можно вернуть любую необходимую для сортировки колонку (в примере P_ID) плюс число N, по которому итоговый order будет понимать что является каментом первого уровня, а что его дочерними.

Comment: Он ругается на N в седьмой строке `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'N
          from (select id,
                       (select id from _fx_commen' at line 7 */` Я думал что дело в том что if'ы не взяты в скобки - но нет. Пока это выглядит чем-то очень запутанным для моего восприятия)

Comment: @sanu0074 Запятую забыл после P_ID. Я же примерно набросал, вашей БД для проверки у меня нет. тренировался на простенькой своей табличке.

Comment: это уже мой косяк, я не досмотрел. Я может чего-то недопонял, можете мне объяснить. Вот таблица: http://hkar.ru/KdSK а вот текущий результат выборки http://hkar.ru/KdSP Получается что дочерними должны быть выбраны записи с id 7,8 для для pid = 5 и 13, 4 для pid = 3. Но выборка выглядит странно, у всех N=1 и у всех есть pid. И я не пойму как все же различить дочерние записи от корневых.

Comment: @sanu0074 У вас изначальное условие в вопросе (pid is not null) странное. У корневых записей pid должен быть NULL. Так что основной запрос должен по хорошему выбирать только их. Тогда и дочерние у них найдутся

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, это очень интересно и познавательно для меня!

Comment: сотрите, я вот сделал: выборка: http://hkar.ru/KdXM, сама таблица: http://hkar.ru/KdXN. И все равно что-то не так, строки дублируются, и дочерние извлекаются все а не два последних, такое чувство что LIMIT 0,1 / 1,1 не работает. Или я опять что-то не так сделал

Comment: @sanu0074 У вас эти записи один раз выбираются основным запросом (N=1) и второй раз как дочерние (N>1). Добавьте условие `pid is null` в основной запрос, что бы он брал только корневые записи

Comment: да так правильно работает, спасибо. Я запутался, т.к. изначально у меня так и было потом убрал

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую такую пару ссылок по тематике вашего вопроса:

- Про Netsted Set для mysql http://habrahabr.ru/post/153861
- Базовые три алгоритма построения деревьев: http://habrahabr.ru/post/46659

Структура данных в базе выбрана правильно: AL подходит лучше всего.

Вообще, раз у вас всегда два последних комментария: используйте такую возможность mysql как limit 0, 1 и limit 1,1 для получения своих комментариев и не парьтесь насчёт перехода на NS.

Конкретнее. Используйте два запроса. Выбираете дочерние комментарии, отсортированные по дате. В первом запросе limit 0,1 (последний комментарий), во втором запросе limit 1,1 (предпоследний комментарий. Устраивает?

```
SELECT
  `c1`.`id`,
  `c1`.`pid`,
  (SELECT id FROM `_fx_comments` AS `c` WHERE `c`.`pid` = `c1`.`id`  ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS last_comment,
  (SELECT id FROM `_fx_comments` AS `c` WHERE `c`.`pid` = `c1`.`id`  ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS prev_last_comment      

FROM `_fx_comments` AS `c1`
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Вот вам будут id записей, которые вам нужны (либо NULL если таковых записей не будет).

Решение для конкретно вашего вопроса. Подходит?

Comment: Не совсем, таким образом я получаю доп поля в выборке  -http://hkar.ru/Kd4v, а мне нужны полноценные записи со всеми полями. т.е. Как по полученным id подтянуть все данные о комменте?

Comment: делать два джоина? и тогда будет много полей типа prev_last_comment_sender,last_comment_sender, last_comment_date ... и т.д. Это вариант конечно, но не думаю что самый лучший

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что вы не очень хорошо понимаете SQL. Такого не сделать в рамках одного запроса. Попробуйте открыть эксель и набросать, как по-вашему должен выглядеть ответ, как вы будете отделять "настоящие" строки таблицы от виртаульной последней и виртуальной предпоследней.

Comment: Да, я не оч в SQL, но мне показалось что можно добавить в выборку строки с дочерними комментами не расширяя ее столбцами типа prev_last_comment_sender,last_comment_sender, last_comment_date ... а потом перед выдачей отсортировать данные в массив. Хотя возможно это - плохой вариант, я не уверен

Comment: У вас 13 столбцов (id, pid, sender...). Вы хотите добавить ещё 13 столбцов (last_comment_id, last_comment_pid, last_comment_sender...) и ещё 13 столбцов для предыдущего комментария. Не то, чтобы это совсем невозможно, но это настолько плохая практика, б-р-р-р-р, что не рекомендую рассматривать в качестве решения.

Comment: да, вот и я об этом) как-то плохо будет из-за двух комментов расширять выборку >30 столбцов, а если потом станет задача вывести 5 комментов (ну вдруг), тогда будет еще больше столбцов, и это ужасно) Поэтому я у вас и интерисуюсь, что может эти комменты можно просто как-то добавить в эту же выборку, а потом отсортировать данные в соответствующий массив...