# Проектирование БД магазина с иерархическими категориями

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Есть связаные сущности: "Категории" и "Продукты". Есть 3 задачи которые необходимо разрешить:

1. Продукты могут пренадлежать сразу нескольким категориям.
2. Категории иерархичны и могут содержать свои подкатегории с теоретически любым уровнем вложености. Но на практике наверно не более 10-15. Тут я совсем не пойму как это организовать в таблицах и как потом связать эти иерархически категории с конкретными Продуктами.
3. Нужно написать запрос к категориям, который будет возвращаться всю ветку. Т.е. все продукты в указанной категории, ее подкатегории (если  в них присутствуют товары) и т.д.

БД: MySQl / SQL server express /SQLite / другая... - главное на чем быстрее и легче реализовать.

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку и/или похожий пример.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем?

Comment: вопрос в том как все это реализовать

Comment: 1) Определить требования 2) Составить схему БД 3) собрать эту схему в нужной вам субд

Comment: У вас основной вопрос про дерево категорий, почитайте эти [статьи с хабра](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553152/213987) -- будет вводная о том, как это реализуется.

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз нужна подсказка, то мое виденье такое:

1) Связи многие ко многим=> нужная третья таблица для реализации этой связи.

2) Я вижу таблицу с рекурсивной связью(Таблица, которая соединяется сама на себя `CTE`-`COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION в MS SQL`).

Что-то типа:

```
CategoryId|Name|SubCategoryId
```

Если категория находится в самом низу иерархии и от нее нету потомков, то `CategoryId=NULL`.

Соответственно, сможешь восстановить дерево.

Есть еще вариант в виде использования XML, но это, на мой взгляд, не очень производительно.

3)Рекурсивный `CTE`.

Правда, на мой взгляд вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Я как то давно писал про [рекурсивные sql запросы](http://blog.muradov.pro/post/2012/10/30/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-SQL-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B), надеюсь автору чем т поможет

Comment: *(Таблица, которая соединяется сама на себя CTE-COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION в MS SQL)* CTE не имеет НИКАКОГО отношения к внутренним связям в таблице.

Comment: в sql-server ктсати есть тип данных [`hierarchyid`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server) и функции для соответствующей выборки.

Comment: @teran, а с какой версии появилась? Впервые слышу об этом типе.

Comment: @iluxa1810 с 2008й

Comment: @teran, хм... А работа с ним прозрачна? Т.е могу ли я с ним, как с INT работать?