# трёхуровневое меню

Tags: php

Надо у подкатегории вывести подкатегорию.

Убил 2 дня, перепробовал всякие способы, в итоге сделал свой велосипед на костылях, рекурсией мне такое задание сделать очень сложно.

Такой код допускается на проекте? Какой способ ещё есть?

Делаю запрос

```
SELECT
    category.id AS catId, category.name AS catName,
    sub_category.id AS subCatId, sub_category.name AS subCatName,
    page.id AS pageId, page.name AS pageName

FROM category LEFT JOIN sub_category
ON sub_category.category_id = category.id LEFT JOIN page
ON page.sub_category_id = sub_category.id ORDER BY category.id
```

Мне присылается вот такой массив

```
$res = [
        ['catId' => 1, 'catName' => 'Программы', 'subCatId' => 1, 'subCatName' => "Антивирусы", 'pageId' => "1", 'pageName' => "Касперский"],
        ['catId' => 1, 'catName' => 'Программы', 'subCatId' => 4, 'subCatName' => "Аудио", 'pageId' => "4", 'pageName' => "VirtualDJ"],
        ['catId' => 1, 'catName' => 'Программы', 'subCatId' => 4, 'subCatName' => "Аудио", 'pageId' => "5", 'pageName' => "FL Studio"],
        ['catId' => 1, 'catName' => 'Программы', 'subCatId' => 1, 'subCatName' => "Антивирусы", 'pageId' => "6", 'pageName' => "NOD32"],
        ['catId' => 1, 'catName' => 'Программы', 'subCatId' => 2, 'subCatName' => "Запись", 'pageId' => "NULL", 'pageName' => "NULL"],
        ['catId' => 1, 'catName' => 'Программы', 'subCatId' => 3, 'subCatName' => "Интернет", 'pageId' => "NULL", 'pageName' => "NULL"],
        ['catId' => 2, 'catName' => 'Фильмы',    'subCatId' => 5, 'subCatName' => "Боевики", 'pageId' => "2", 'pageName' => "Джпеки Чан"],
        ['catId' => 2, 'catName' => 'Фильмы',    'subCatId' => 7, 'subCatName' => "Ужастики", 'pageId' => "3", 'pageName' => "Псы войны"],
        ['catId' => 2, 'catName' => 'Фильмы',    'subCatId' => 5, 'subCatName' => "Боевики", 'pageId' => "8", 'pageName' => "Американский ниндзя"],
        ['catId' => 2, 'catName' => 'Фильмы',    'subCatId' => 6, 'subCatName' => "Фантастика", 'pageId' => "NULL", 'pageName' => "NULL"],
    ];
```

Потом я из него делаю другой массив, который мне нужен.
Вот так я его делаю

```
$mass = [];
foreach($res as $cat) {
    if (!array_key_exists($cat['catName'] . '|' . $cat['catId'], $mass)) {
        $mass[$cat['catName'] . '|' . $cat['catId']] = [$cat['subCatName'] . '|' . $cat['subCatId']=> [$cat['pageId']=>$cat['pageName']]];
    }

    else {
        $mass[$cat['catName']. '|' .$cat['catId']][$cat['subCatName'] . '|' .$cat['subCatId']][$cat['pageId']]=$cat['pageName'];
    }
}
```

После этого получился вот такой массив

```
Array
(
    [Программы|1] => Array
        (
            [Антивирусы|1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Касперский
                    [6] => NOD32
                )

            [Аудио|4] => Array
                (
                    [4] => VirtualDJ
                    [5] => FL Studio
                )

            [Запись|2] => Array
                (
                    [] =>
                )

            [Интернет|3] => Array
                (
                    [] =>
                )

        )

    [Фильмы|2] => Array
        (
            [Боевики|5] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Джеки Чан
                    [8] => Американский ниндзя
                )

            [Ужастики|7] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Псы войны
                )

            [Фантастика|6] => Array
                (
                    [] =>
                )

        )

)
```

И потом уже, создаю списки

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($mass as $key => $val) {
    $category = explode('|', $key);
    echo '<li><a href="/category/'.$category[1].'">'.$category[0].'</a>';
         foreach($val as $k => $v) {
            $subCategory = explode('|', $k);
                echo '<ul>';
                    echo '<li><a href="/sub-category/'.$subCategory[1].'">'.$subCategory[0].'</a>';
                         foreach($v as $postKey => $postVal) {
                            echo '<ul>';
                                echo '<li><a href="/post/'.$postKey.'">'.$postVal.'</a></li>';
                            echo '</ul>';
                         }
                    echo '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
         }
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Получается вот такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот скажите честно, вас не утомляет писать несколько раз такие вот выражения `$cat['catName'] . '|' . $cat['catId']` ? что мешает завести в первой строке цикла `$ckey = ...` и дальше использовать? боитесь лишних переменных что ли? ключ легче модифицировать один раз и в одном месте, код короче и лучше читаем, шанс опечаток снижается в разы.

Comment: ссылки на хабр из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553152/213987) почитайте.

Comment: по другому не додумался

Comment: мне в свое время помогла вот эта статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/280944/